# Access GCS from cloudrun

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I have a php project here that I want to run in Google Cloud Run, since it also works with files, I thought it makes sense to start a GSC instance and put files there.

Locally this has also worked so far. However, as soon as I run the project in Cloud Run, I get the error when accessing GCS:

```
cURL error 5: Could not resolve proxy: null (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/<redacted>/o?delimiter=%2F&includeTrailingDelimiter=true&prefix=public%2Fvar%2Ftmp%2Fthumbnails%2F_default_upload_bucket%2F&prettyPrint=false
```

If I understand correctly, cURL wants to go through a proxy, however, I have not configured anything like that. I only have a VPC connector on the cloud run, but it is configured so that only requests to private IPs go through the VPC connector.

The framework used is Symfony 5 and the library to connect is "flysystem" with the "google-cloud-storage" adapter.

Is there something here that I am essentially misunderstanding?

Comment: If you follow the link from the [cURL error](https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/%3Credacted%3E/o?delimiter=%2F&includeTrailingDelimiter=true&prefix=public%2Fvar%2Ftmp%2Fthumbnails%2F_default_upload_bucket%2F&prettyPrint=false), it will show `"The specified bucket does not exist."`. If it doesn't help, I think you will need to add more information to the description, like how do you run in Cloud Run and how the Cloud Storage was referenced

Comment: yes, I have also removed the name of the bucket from the link, because I may not have configured the permissions correctly. - That's why you get the message that this bucket does not exit. 

I am not sure what information you need. I deploy a container with Debian via Terraform, the Terraform code is executed via a pipeline. The storage should be accessed via http, the settings for it are set via env variables. The server user from cloud run is then used for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem. However, I am still not quite clear why I had to do that.

Anyway, the following environment variables must be set for this to work:

```
HTTPS_PROXY = ""
HTTP_PROXY = ""
```